# How to catch an exception for a static object defined in a WndProc() function?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How to catch an exception thrown by the static object `a` in the pseudo-code below, where `WndProc()` is the standard message processing function in the Win32 API ?

```
class A
{
    public:
    class Exception{};
    A() throw(Exception) { ... }
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, UINT wParam, LONG lParam)
{
    static A a;

    switch( message )
    {
        case WM_CREATE:

        ...

        break;

        ...

        default:

        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't raise exceptions that don't get handled in a window procedure.  A backstop in the message loop sorta works but it is troublesome.  Windows tends to swallow exceptions when you run a 32-bit process on a 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: Use a static pointer, initialized to NULL, and create the class instance when WM_CREATE is called.

Comment: Thanks. If you answer the question I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston If you answer the question I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a static pointer, initialized to NULL, and create the class instance when WM_CREATE is called.

Of course, for any message other than WM_CREATE, if you will be using the instance you should double-check that the pointer is not NULL - just in case you're getting messages in an unexpected order.

Answer (score 1):

Function-level statics for non POD structures are intialized the first time the function is invoked you can wrap the code block in a `try and catch` and catch the exception like any normal case

Comment: I see a problem with this approach. To abort window creation, the recommended procedure is to return -1 in WM_CREATE. How am I going to do that in the catch clause ?

Comment: @user1042389 why not return -1 in the `catch clause` would that be an issue ?

Comment: Yes it will be an issue, since you'll be returning -1 for a message other than WM_CREATE. Windows sends several messages to a WndProc(), before WM_CREATE.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but my feeling is that there must be a better (simple, more elegant) way of catching an exception thrown by a static object in WndProc().

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch that within the WndProc, as you shouldn't let a C++ exception propagate "out of" the WndProc.  (this applies to all Windows callbacks)

If the WndProc code isn't "under your control", you can provide a wrapper WndProc instead.

You need to implement a reporting mechanism for later processing, e.g.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcNoX(....)
{
   try
   {
      static A a;
      ...
   }
   catch(Exception const & x)
   {
      // What do you want to happen?
      // e.g.: add x to a log, or a list of "unhandled" exceptions 
      // that you process e.g. in an Idle or OnTimer handle,
      // or make otherwise accessible.


      return 0; // (*)
   }
}
```

(*) is a secondary problem: while 0 is a "fairly safe" return value for most messages, this can lead to problems, e.g. when caller asks for the leng of a buffer they need to pass to another message. BOOM!

To protect against that, you would have to put a try/catch around all individual handlers, and decide on an "in case of error" return value for each message.

Another option is to pass the message on to the default handler in case of an error, btu that might also be problematic with some messages.

Comment: I see a problem with this approach. To abort window creation, the recommended procedure is to return -1 in WM_CREATE. How am I going to do that in the catch clause ?

Comment: @user1042389 Change the `return` statement appropriately.

Comment: I think any return from the catch clause will happen before the message WM_CREATE is sent to WndProc().

Comment: @user1042389: See the comment below the sample

Comment: How to abort the window creation, while catching the exception ? The exception will be caught in the first message sent by the OS, which is WM_GETMINMAXINFO. If I return 0 in the catch clause, as you suggest, the window will still be created, with an object that was not constructed.